Prove that PCA decomposition captures all information in a factor model
Assume a data matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times p_X}$. Let it have some exact lower dimensional factor representation $X = A F$, where $F \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times p_F}$ and $p_F < p_X$. Let the weight matrix corresponding to the first $p_F$ principal components be $W$ so the transformed / dimension reduced data is $T=XW$. Note that the number of principal components is the same as there are "true" factors.
I think now the PCA decomposition captures all of the variance in $X$. In particular a least squares projection $x_i=T_i\beta$ has an $R^2$ of 100%. However, how to formally prove this?

Your hypothesis is correct.
From the assumption that $X = AF$, we can guarantee that $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq p_F$. Now, let $\mathbf 1 \in \Bbb R^{N}$ denote the all-ones vector, let $\mu = [\frac{\mathbf 1^TX}{N}]^T$ denote the mean row (as a column vector), and let $P$ denote the projection matrix $P = I_{N} - \frac 1{N}\mathbf 1 \mathbf 1^T$. We note that the mean-centered data is given by
$$
\tilde X = PX = X - \mathbf 1 \mu^T.
$$
Because it generally holds that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \operatorname{rank}(B)$, we know that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(\tilde X)
= \operatorname{rank}(PX) \leq \operatorname{rank}(X) \leq p_F.
$$
Now, the rank of $\tilde X$ is also equal to the number of non-zero singular values it has. It follows that the full SVD of $\tilde X$ can be written in the following form:
$$
\tilde X = \pmatrix{V & V_0}\pmatrix{\Sigma & 0\\0 & 0_{(N-p_F) \times (p_X - p_F)}} \pmatrix{W  & W_0}^T,
$$
where the shapes of each labeled submatrix above are as follows

$V:N \times p_F$
$V_0:N \times (N - p_F)$
$\Sigma: p_F \times p_F$
$W:p_X \times p_F$
$W_0: p_X \times (p_F - p_X)$.

Now, with block-matrix multiplication, we can see that the above can be rewritten as
$$
\tilde X = V \Sigma W^T.
$$
(Note: this differs from the compact SVD in the case that $\text{rank}(\tilde X) < p_F$). Thus, we have $X = V \Sigma W^T + \mathbf 1 \mu^T$.
Now, to see that the reduced data $T = XW$ captures all variance, it suffices to note that the "inverse-transformed" or "recovered" data $TW^T$ is simply a shifted version of the original data set. Indeed,
$$
\begin{align}
TW^T &= 
XWW^T 
\\ & = (\tilde X  +  \mathbf 1 \mu^T)WW^T
\\ & = \tilde X WW^T + \mathbf 1 (\mu^TWW^T)
\\ & = V \Sigma (W^TW)W^T + \mathbf 1 (\mu^TWW^T)
\\ & = V \Sigma W^T + \mathbf 1 (\mu^TWW^T)
\\ & = \tilde X + \mathbf 1 (\mu^TWW^T)
\\ & = X -  \mathbf 1 \mu^T + \mathbf 1 (\mu^TWW^T)
\\ & = X - \mathbf 1\mu^T(I - WW^T).
\end{align}
$$
That is, the recovered data $TW^T$ can be obtained by taking the original data set and simply subtracting the row-vector $\mu^T(I - WW^T)$ from every row.
Incidentally, the vector $\mu^T(I - WW^T)$ (or if you prefer, the corresponding column-vector $(I - WW^T)\mu$) is the component of $\mu$ that is orthogonal to the row space of $\tilde X$, i.e. the component of the mean that is orthogonal to all principal components.

Thanks, looks good. I will think through before accepting.

@fes You're welcome. Happy to answer any questions
